# Return indexes of xRange in Dygrpahs

Tags: dygraphs

Is it possible to retrieve the indexes of the visible xRange in Dygraphs? xAxisRange() returns the value of the low end and high end. Something similar how highlightCallback returns a "row".

I'm using dygraphs 1.1.1